# Does Google Maps API offer a way to search for locations by name?

Tags: javascript, api, search, google-maps, geocoding

When one visits http://maps.google.com, they are able to type queries into the search field and receive results based on locations or places, and not hard search results, as they would in a normal Google Search query. They're a unique style of result (names of places, locations) suited to the Maps interface for obvious reasons.

I've been digging through both the Maps and standard Google Search API for a couple hours now, and have done multiple searches on this question, and I can't seem to find the answer.

They obviously have the Local Search, but that's been deprecated, and it only yields results if you provide an initial lat/long. I want to be able to find places or locations with no initial lat/long.

Essentially what I want to do is allow a user to type in an address, name of a place or name of a city or state or a zip code, or essentially any other kind of location that is allowable on Maps, and geocode it. I feel stupid because this seems like it has to be there, but nothing I've seen in the API seems to do this.

I don't need the AJAX suggested results, necessarily. Just a way for a user to type in a nice name and geocode from it, though results as a user types would be ideal.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you are looking is Geocoding API from google maps.

[Find Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

**UPDATE 5/12/2011**

Google just opened up public access to their Places API. This is more to the heart of the original question request:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete

Comment: This is the same documentation I mentioned above. It says it will geocode by address, not name. Is that inaccurate? Will it also geocode by name?

Comment: After running a quick test case, it appears it does. Thanks for helping. I need sleep.

Comment: New doc URLs:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places/

and

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: The first reference "Find documentation here" is invalid.

Comment: Link broken to the second

Comment: fixed the links.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [`google.maps.Geocoder`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Geocoder) class:

> A service for converting between an address and a LatLng.