# Does Google Maps API offer a way to search for locations by city name?

Tags: php, google-maps

As far as I am aware the auto-complete search field can only be restricted by country using the `ComponentRestrictions` object within the places library. Whilst you can specify `latlngbounds` in order to bias the results it would be more useful to be also able to restrict the search results to specified `latlng` bounds. In addition to this I think it would be useful for the ComponentRestrictions object within the places library to be able to specify specific cities (eg. Sydney, Australia).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Google Maps API offer a way to search for locations by name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926369/does-google-maps-api-offer-a-way-to-search-for-locations-by-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature request for this already exists in the public issue tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4433

Please star this feature request to express your interest and receive updates from Google.